# python xlwt set custom background colour of a cell

Tags: python, excel, format, xlwt

I am using python 2.7 and xlwt module for excel export

I would like to set backgroung colour of a cell
i know i can use

```
style1 = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour red;')
```

but I would like to set custom color smth. like #8a8eef
or is there a palette of possible colors, because light blue is not working :)

thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are not using `easyxf()` and instead are building `XFStyle` object step by step, here is another way of using user friendly color names:

```
import xlwt

style = xlwt.XFStyle()
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['dark_purple']
style.pattern = pattern
```

Answer (score 35):

Nowadays, there is a way (originally proposed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/HmGnhYpV094)) to define and use custom colour using `add_palette_colour()` and `set_colour_RGB()`.

Here's an example:

```
import xlwt


book = xlwt.Workbook()

# add new colour to palette and set RGB colour value
xlwt.add_palette_colour("custom_colour", 0x21)
book.set_colour_RGB(0x21, 251, 228, 228)

# now you can use the colour in styles
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour custom_colour')
sheet1.write(0, 0, 'Some text', style)

book.save('test.xls')
```

Also see the actual [pull request](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/pull/2) that made this happen.

Comment: In your example, you used `0x21`. Is there any reason you picked that? If I want to add more, should I use `0x22`, `0x23`, and so on?

Comment: @Nick [source code](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/917a8ad8db35d6e8abb306a2fda2ace648a6ab89/xlwt/Style.py#L374) suggests that `0x21` can be any number in range `8 <= colour_index <= 63`

Comment: Note that you can omit `add_palette_colour` by overwriting an existing palette color. Example: `book.set_colour_RGB(0x16, 245, 245, 245); style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour gray25')`

Comment: NB: although `add_palette_colour()` accepts upper case letters in color names, trying to use them in `easyxf()` fails. Make sure you apply `.lower()` if needs be.

Answer (score 6):

For predefined colors see `xlwt.Style._colour_map_text` in [Style.py](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Style.py).

To use custom colors you will have to probably redefine palette, because colors are not used directly in cells but as a index to color in a palette. I don't know how to extend palette. Sorry.

Comment: is there any way to add custom RGB colour to cell?

Answer (score 2):

***Alternative solution:***

If you can get away with the colors defined in xlwt, go to a color information site like http://www.colorhexa.com/90ee90 and match from one of the following Python Excel colors: http://bit.ly/1NMH67F

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use XlsxWriter, has awesome features too.
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: XlsxWriter has more intuitive API b/c it uses key value pairs to set the formats

Comment: xlwt is for old xls format, while xlsxwriter is for the new format, so they're not interchangeable.