# missing attribute error when trying to set cell color in xlwt using python

Tags: python, excel, runtime-error, xlwt

I'm trying to change the color of my excel spreadsheet to color code data using python's xlwt package.  Here's my current code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from tempfile import Temporary File
from xlwt
import sys
import csv

....
....#Some other code

style = xlwt.XFStyle() #this is the line throwing the error
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['red']

pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['red']
newSheet.write(row, col, values[row - 1][col], pattern)

....
....#Some other code
```

Other code sections are there because it is a longer script than shown but those sections of code aren't related to this problem

I get the following stack trace when it runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "excel-procesor.py", line 85, in <module>
        newSheet.write(row, col, values[row - 1][col], pattern)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 234, in write self.__adjust_height(style)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 64, in __adjust_height
        twip = style.font.height
AttributeError: 'Pattern' object has no attribute 'font'
```

I'm using [How to change background color of excel cell with python xlwt library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532367/how-to-change-background-color-of-excel-cell-with-python-xlwt-library) and [python xlwt set custom background colour of a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746837/python-xlwt-set-custom-background-colour-of-a-cell) as guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code:

```
xlwt.Worksheet.write(self, r, c, label='', style=<xlwt.Style.XFStyle object at 0x053AEA10>)
```

`write` should receive the `style` as argument, and not directly the `Pattern` object.

You should try to put your pattern object into `style` and pass `style` as argument:

```
style.pattern = pattern
newSheet.write(row, col, values[row - 1][col], style)
```

Some [examples](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2011/04/examples-generating-excel-documents-using-pythons-xlwt/) I found useful how to use `xlwt`, including how to set the style