# Compare two csv files and color code the difference in csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to compare two CSV files. If there is difference in a particular cell (Ex: 5th row and 3rd column) then give red color to that cell.

I can able to compare two files but unable to give red color to the difference cell I have tried this code

```
def compare():
try:
    assert_frame_equal(df_sort_sas, df_sort_py)
    return True
except:  # appeantly AssertionError doesn't catch all
    return False 
compare()
```

I want output like this:
Here red colored cell means that particular value is not equal with first csv cell

[image]

Comment: You want to add colors to "CSV" files? This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a colour in a csv file. Want you can do is doing it in excel: 
Have a look at those two questions: [How to change background color of excel cell with python xlwt library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10532367/3659824) and [Setting a cell's fill RGB color with pywin32 in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11444207/3659824)

To summen up the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542220/3659824):

```
from xlwt import Workbook
import xlwt
book = Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
book.add_sheet('Sheet 2')
for i in range(0, 100):
    st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
    st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = i
    sheet1.write(i % 24, i / 24, 'Test text',st)
book.save('simple.xls')
```

or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445155/3659824):

```
def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    strValue = '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb
    iValue = int(strValue, 16)
    return iValue

xl.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).interior.color = rgb_to_hex((255,255,0))
```

Credits to the authors not me

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply conditional formatting to excel files (e.g. xlsx), not .csv

I would organise the code in the following way:

- Use pandas to compare the two csv and create a dataframe with a flag for the differences
- Use xlsx module to write a xlsx file, coloring in red the cells where you have mismatch  (http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html?highlight=conditional%20formatting)

Hope this helps