# How to set color of text using xlwt

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I haven't been able to find documentation on how to set the color of text. How would the following be done in xlwt?

```
style = xlwt.XFStyle()

# bold
font = xlwt.Font()
font.bold = True
style.font = font

# background color
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['pale_blue']
style.pattern = pattern

# color of text
???
```

Another way I have tried, where I've been able to set the font color but not the background color is:

```
style = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1, color red;')
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked:

```
style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour light_blue;'
                              'font: colour white, bold True;')
```

Answer (score 7):

Set "colour_index" attribute.

```
   style.font.colour_index = xlwt.Style.colour_map['white']
```

Answer (score 3):

***Alternative solution:***

If you can get away with the [colors defined in xlwt](http://bit.ly/1NMH67F), go to a color information site like http://www.colorhexa.com/90ee90 and get the closest match.

Answer (score 2):

For the font color **font.color** should do it where for the cell background color there is a similar question:

[python xlwt set custom background colour of a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746837/python-xlwt-set-custom-background-colour-of-a-cell)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the following code:

```
from xlwt import Workbook,XFStyle,Borders, Pattern, Font, easyxf

styleOK = easyxf('pattern: fore_colour light_blue;'
                          'font: colour green, bold True;')
```

Comment: row1.write(4,'KO',styleKO)

Answer (score 0):

```
from xlwt import *
import xlwt

w = Workbook()
sheet1= w.add_sheet('Test')

st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = 20 #random color number
sheet1.write(0, 0,'Random Text',st)

w.save('Random_xls.xls')
```

Comment: One or two senteces as explaination would be nice.

Comment: Provifing that we know that we can create sheets with the first sentences, easyfx helps you to fix the cells. It is necessary to run the st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;') and then you can choose the attributes of the pattern. For the range of the colors I am not sure, but you can print them in a for from 0 to 100 and pick one. Then you choose the cell to write in and apply the style created.

Answer (score 0):

style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour light_blue;'
                                  'font: colour white, bold True;')

```
    sheet.write(row, 0, "Code", style)
    sheet.write(row, 1, "Name", style)
    sheet.write(row, 2, "bottle",style)
```