# Coloring Single Column of Pandas Dataframe.to_html()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Before this is marked as duplicate, I have tried the code from the following topics and none has worked for me thus far:

[[Colouring one column of pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388149/colouring-one-column-of-pandas-dataframe) ]

[[Format the color of a cell in a panda dataframe according to multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839112/format-the-color-of-a-cell-in-a-panda-dataframe-according-to-multiple-conditions) ]

[[how to color selected columns in python dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408246/how-to-color-selected-columns-in-python-dataframe) ]

I have code that produces three pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
         RowName   Orders   Market  StartTime  StopTime
Status
good     A          9       gold    10:00:00    10:09:45
                             .         
                             .
                             .
bad      B          60      silver  07:54:43    08:02:12

         RowName   Orders   Market  StartTime  StopTime
Status
good     E          19      plat.    10:00:00    10:09:45
                             .         
                             .
bad      F          54      mercury  07:54:43    08:02:12

         RowName   Orders   Market  StartTime  StopTime
Status
great     D          3       alum.   10:00:00    10:09:45
                             .         
                             .
ok        C          70      bronze  07:54:43    08:02:12
```

where the `Status` column is set as the index of each frame

**For each frame**, I want to highlight the `StartTime` column with the value `#D42A2A` (aka red) regardless of what value is in a given cell.

How can this be done?

MOST RECENT FAILED ATTEMPTS:

1. `def column_style(col):
        if col.Name == 'StartTime':
            return pd.Series('bgcolor: #d42a2a', col.index)`
2. `def col_color(data):
        color = 'red' if data != '' else 'black'
        return 'color: %s' %color
    frame.style.applymap(col_color, subset=['StartTime'])`

but this also fails.

NOTE:

1. I am using VI within a linux shell
2. The entire script is being called by IE (internet explorer) so the output of the script is html
3. I am using BS (beautifulsoup) to scrape data from a few sites and the aggregating the results onto one page
   {*after scraping the initial website and creating the required website (call it Page1), I tried to scrape Page1 in the same script and add in the html lines via the `.attrs` method, but this "fails", i.e. the webserver times out during the run}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

def highlight_column(s, col):
    return ['background-color: #d42a2a' if s.name == col else '' for v in s.index]

df.style.apply(highlight_column, col = 'B')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This was one of the ways that I saw but could not quite grasp. Do you mind editing this to be applicable to the dataframe above, i.e. renaming the appropriate variables

Comment: Just change `col = 'B'` to `col='StartTime'` and apply to your dataframe.

Comment: Gotcha. After trying this method, the background is still white unfortunately

Comment: df.head().to_dict() what is the output of that?

Comment: I don't see any 'bgcolor' attrs in the resulting dictionary. Result is `{ 'RowName': {'bad': 'B'}, 'Orders': {'bad': '60'}, ... , 'StopTime': {'bad': '08:02:12'} }`

Comment: What ide are you using?  Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with your environment.  If you run this code as is does it produce the red columN?

Comment: Lets move this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184835/discussion-between-swagless-monk-and-scott-boston).

Comment: It turns out that your `def highlight_column(s, col)` was exactly correct. The only thing that needed configuring was in the call. So calling the function should be this:    `df.style.apply(highlight_column, col='B').render(table_styles='default')`. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to also change color of column names?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using BeautifulSoup to parse a website and then using pandas to create a DataFrame that you may want to add styles to, you can do something like:

(before using this you have already; imported beautifulsoup, scraped your site and created your dataframe)

`variable_name = beautifulsoup(dataframe_name.to_html())`

`list = []`

```
`for table in variable_name.findAll('table'):`

  `for tbody in variable_name.findAll('table'):`

    `for td in variable_name.findAll('tbody'):`

         `list.append(td)`
```

`list[td_index]['attribute_name'] = 'attribute_value'`

This will add your all your table data to a list and you can select any element from that list and add/update a tag attribute

(if more efficient way please comment to help improve)