# coloring a row based on the column value using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which looks like this
[picture of the df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMtSP.png)

I want to color the row where the value of value column is 5 using pandas? how to do that?
For above example, I want to color the John and Linda row.

Comment: Do you want to color the row in Excel ? Or in your IDE i.e dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to apply color on particular cells, you can simply use lambda function of pandas:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: red" if x>0 else "background-color: white")
```

Pandas has a Styler feature where you can apply conditional formatting type manipulations to Dataframes. [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['John', 'Doe', 'Linda']
df['value'] = [5, 9, 5]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FF1717',
                               'font_color': '#990000'})
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 1, len(df), 1,
                             {'type': 'cell',
                              'criteria': '==',
                              'value': 5,
                              'format': format1})
writer.save()
```

[image]

The uploaded picture looks like Excel. It's the way to save on Excel with color.

This page will help you.
[How to save pandas to excel with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109548/how-to-save-pandas-to-excel-with-different-colors)