# how to add formatting for a range of cells with using xlwt

Tags: python-3.x, xlwt

I want to add colour to range of cells. How can i do this with using`xlwt`?

I could only find many solutions for formatting a single cell like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746837/python-xlwt-set-custom-background-colour-of-a-cell).

Comment: what did you try? where are you stuck? sharing minimal code which replicates your issue will help

Comment: I'm trying to split every three rows by color in for 30 columns. I can not set the color in parallel with the value because not all the cells write the value and these cells will differ in color.

Comment: let's see some code...